# How to pass strongly typed complex object to ajax method in mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class called `ReferralModel` that which has properties that consist of other objects:

```
public class ReferralModel
{
    public Referral Referral { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a sample of the `Address` class:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to construct the object on client side to send through via Ajax but get a syntax error when trying to construct the object this way:

```
var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("AjaxCreateReferral", "Referral")",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                referralModel: {
                    ReferralModel.Address.Address1: $("#txtAddress1").val(),
                    ReferralModel.Address.Address2: $("#txtAddress2").val()
                }
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response)
            {
                var dataObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $("#hidPatientId").text(dataObject.patientId);
            }
        });
```

Visual Studio does not like the `ReferralModel.Address.Address1` line. Is there a way to construct this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well

```
referralModel: {
  ReferralModel.Address.Address1: $("#txtAddress1").val(),
  ReferralModel.Address.Address2: $("#txtAddress2").val()
}
```

Does not appear to come close to matching:

```
public class ReferralModel
{
  public Referral Referral { get; set; }
  public Address Address { get; set; }
  public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

You want to match property names not types, so it should probably should look like:

```
// Start of the object in the signature
// in the example below will be ReferralModel model
{
  // name of a property in the signature model
  // model.Address
  Address: 
  {
    // name of a property in the class of the previous property
    // model.Address.Address1 (etc)
    Address1: $("#txtAddress1").val(),
    Address2: $("#txtAddress2").val()
  }
}
```

This is assuming you have an method with a signature similar to:

```
public ActionResult Index(ReferralModel model)
{
  //...
}
```

Additionally this is really not the preferred way to handle returned JSON.

```
dataType: "text",
success: function (response)
{
  var dataObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
  $("#hidPatientId").text(dataObject.patientId);
```

per the jQuery Docs:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> ..if none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object..

so it can easily be reduced to:

```
success: function (dataObject)
{
  $("#hidPatientId").text(dataObject.patientId);
```

Comment: Thanks Erik, needed a little help with the syntax structure and that fixed it!

Comment: Once I got to know the ModelBinder, I found it so incredibly easy to use.